# Reference that details BG verse 15.13

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Bhagavad Gita verse 15.13 says,

> puṣhṇāmi chauṣhadhīḥ sarvāḥ somo bhūtvā rasātmakaḥ
>
> Plants (aushadhihi) are sustained(nourished) by moon.

Any reference that details this phenomenon ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brief description of this phenomenon maybe found in the Viṣṇu Mahā-Purāṇa.

[Chapter XII](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115972.html) - Description of the Moon, Viṣṇu-purāṇa

> **In that orbit the moon is immersed for a day and night in the water;
> thence it enters the branches and shoots of the trees;** and thence goes
> to the sun. **Consequently any one who cuts off a branch, or casts down
> a leaf, when the moon is in the trees (the day of its rising
> invisible), is guilty of Brahmanicide.** When the remaining portion of
> the moon consists of but a fifteenth part, the progenitors approach it
> in the afternoon, and drink the last portion, that sacred Kali which
> is composed of ambrosia, and contained in the two digits of the form
> of the moon. Having drank the nectar effused by the lunar rays on
> the day of conjunction, the progenitors are satisfied, and remain
> tranquil for the ensuing month. These progenitors (or Pitris) are of
> three classes, termed Saumyas, Varhiṣadas, and Agniṣvāttas. **In this
> manner the moon, with its cooling rays, nourishes** the gods in the
> light fortnight, the Pitris in the dark fortnight; **vegetables, with
> the cool nectary aqueous atoms it sheds upon them; and through their
> developement it sustains men, animals, and insects; at the same time
> gratifying them by its radiance.**
>
> English Translation by H.H. Wilson

---

- One may read the Sanskrit + Hindi Translation by the Gita Press Gorakhpur [from here](https://archive.org/details/vishnu-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n159/mode/1up?view=theater).
- And the English Translation version by M.N.Dutt [from here](https://archive.org/details/Vishnupurana-English-MnDutt/page/n165/mode/1up?view=theater).

Answer (score 3):

Jagatguru Adi Shankara while explaining the name of Soma from the Vishnu Sahasranama, in his bhasyam says this:

> **सोमरुपेणौषधीः पोषयन् सोमः** उमया सहितः शिवो वा। (Shankaracharya Vishnu Sahasranama Bhasya)
>
> **Soma: Nourishing the plants in the form of Moon,** or Soma means Shiva who is forever with Uma.